# How do i get a dialog to appear after first click from a Selectable using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, jquery-ui-selectable

I am having trouble getting my dialog to appear after the initial click.
Here is what happens when a Selectable is clicked:

- First click- Nothing
- Second click- First clicks content. Closed. Nothing
- Third Click-  First clicks content. Closed. Another dialog    behind
  with second clicks content. Closed. Nothing.
- Cycle repeats    with previous two selections.

Here is the function:

```
  $(function() {

    $('#selectable').selectable({

        selecting: function (event, ui) {
            //Sends selectable title to recieve information to fill dialog page.  
            $.post('ajax_receiver.php', 'val=' + ui.selecting.id, function (response) {
                //Fills div #contentWindow with jQuery's <div id='dialog'..>
                $("#contentWindow").html(response); 
            });  
           $("#content").html(ui.selecting.id);// get ra

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ modal: true });

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open"); 
            $(event.target).children('.ui-selecting').not(':first').removeClass('ui-selecting');  

        }

    });

    //dialog box that holds informaiton
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "clip",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "clip",
            duration: 500
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Needed to wait until information was received from php before applying to web page.